# Jquery UI sortable inside contente

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I trying sort content inside sortable, so my idea is when we drag element I only want move the content inside the element in this case "div" to an empty "li" keeping the "li" in the some position.

```
            <ul class="mySortable">
              <li><div>Item 1</div></li>
              <li><div>Item 2</div></li>
              <li><div>Item 3</div></li>
              <li><div>Item 4</div></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
            </ul>
```

$('.mySortable').sortable().disableSelection()

I don't know if I need or not use 'draggable' insted 'sortable' to do this, someone can help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant do this using sortable. For sortable, only the immediate child elements of a sortable container can be dragged, in your case, the li.

You need to use draggable and droppable. make your divs draggable and your li's droppable